# How can I have different Queue locations in the Service Block based on the Agent property?

Tags: simulation, anylogic

I have a service block, and the agents entering the service block have a parameter called "BatteryProblem". What I want is, if "agent.BatteryProblem" is true, they stand in a separate queue, and if "agent.BatteryProblem" is false, those agents stand in a separate queue. The challenge is that I want to achieve this with only one service block.

What I tried:
I attempted to set the queue location of the service block based on the agent's "BatteryProblem" parameter. I have provided an image below showing what I tried, but it did not work.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because that code field has no `agent` callback, always study the "magic lightbulb" (see [here](https://www.anylogic.com/blog/the-magic-light-bulb-by-benjamin-schumann/)).

Easiest way to solve this is to use a full `Queue` block upstream (and set the service queue capacity to 1).

The Service block is itself only a combination of Queue, Seize, delay, release. You typically spread it out if you need specific capabilities